# Python: pivot table error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to find the `average hourly trips` on weekends and weekdays for both "Annual Members" and "Short-Term Pass Holder"

Data Frame info:

```
DatetimeIndex: 7795 entries, 2014-10-13 to 2015-10-12
Data columns (total 4 columns):
(hour, )                             7795 non-null int64
(trip_id, Annual Member)             7795 non-null float64
(trip_id, Short-Term Pass Holder)    7795 non-null float64
(weekend, )                          7795 non-null bool
```

Data frame looks like in attached image
[image]

I attempted the below code, but it is not working
    
`by_hour.pivot_table(index=['weekend','hour'],aggfunc ='mean',columns=['Annual Member','Short-Term Pass Holder'])`

Error thrown is:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'start'

Edit: posting the completed code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
trips = pd.read_csv('2015_trip_data.csv', parse_dates=['starttime', 'stoptime'],
                infer_datetime_format=True)
 ind = pd.DatetimeIndex(trips.starttime)
 trips['date'] = ind.date.astype('datetime64')
 trips['hour'] = ind.hour
 by_date = trips.pivot_table(index=['date'],values =['trip_id'], columns='usertype', aggfunc ='count')
 by_weekday=by_date.groupby([by_date.index.year,by_date.index.dayofweek]).mean()
 by_hour = trips.pivot_table(index =['date','hour'], columns =['usertype'],
                        values =['trip_id'], aggfunc ='count').fillna(0).reset_index('hour')
```

Comment: Could you post your full code?